# Replace all rows of a select query with matching rows of another table

Tags: mysql, database

I am wondering if there is a SQL query to this?[image]
Objective: compare user_post.user_id with user_info.id, fetch user_info.profile_page from the matching row and form a table from all the matches.

I have tried INNER, LEFT and Right JOIN.
[image]
Not usefull.

Also, IN doesn't product the desired result either.[image]

Comment: Next time post the code you tried, don't just say you tried it - post the code. Otherwise very nice and clear post.

Comment: Sure, will do. Didn't think people want to bother with reading codes!

Comment: They won't read long code, true. But a query is fine, usually they are short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT profile_page
FROM user_post JOIN user_info
  ON (user_post.user_id = user_info.id)
```

Do you need the .php in the result?

Do you need it as a table, or is a query enough? You can make a view.

Comment: Just the query is enough. I will give this a try. Thank you.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Seems like I need to learn more about ON instead of WHERE

Comment: You can do this with `WHERE` also (the other answer by v2solutions.com shows this), but it's easier and clearer to use `ON`.

Answer (score 1):

Below query should work for you:

```
SELECT
    user_info.profile_page
FROM
    user_info,
    user_post
WHERE 
    user_info.id = user_post.user_id
```